# optimize too many multipe left joins

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Recently I started working on client side for resolving bugs in existing ***ASP.Net*** web application. One of the bugs is performance optimization. I found a table named `[Applications]` with 160 columns. There also a view `[vwApplications]` with 680 columns and 80 left joins in ***SQL server database***.
I cannot reduce column or joins since it is already being used in other parts of application or in other applications.

For example:

```
select a.column1, a.column2......... -- upto 680 columns..
from Applications a
left join table1 on a.id = table1.id
left join .....
left join .... -- upto 80 left joins
```

All the tables have identity column with primary key on it.
I have to optimize this view since it takes 1 min to execute with 10000 records.
I have tried splitting the query and temporary tables to store partial data and finally merged all table into one, but not much success.

Comment: There is nowhere near enough information to help here. We don't what the tables look like, the current query, what you want for output etc...all we know is you have a view that you suspect is slow and you want to make it faster.

Comment: indexing may help, but this also sounds like a ridiculous number of columns in BOTH the `Applications` table and the `vwApplications` view...

Comment: One thing to check is that does the optimization time out, it could happen with joins this complex. You can find reason for termination from the properties of the first object in the plan.

Comment: Without knowing the details, it's difficult to give suggestions. For normal fetches splitting the logic into several pieces using temp. tables could work -- for the view, would it be possible to use indexed view(s), either for the whole thing or at least part of the data?

Comment: Is there any filtering criteria in the where clause?  Anything that could potentially be used for indexes?  Also, without the execution plan, there is no way to know how to tune this beast.

Comment: I would caution against saying things like "too many left joins". In a properly normalized relational database, you will have many, many tables and many `LEFT JOIN`s could be possible depending on the database structure. There is no threshold for too many `JOIN`s. Your speed issue is likely a data structure or indexing issue.

Answer (score 2):

Good day,

Firstly, I agree with  @Sean Lange that There is nowhere near enough information to give you a solution. At least we need the DDL+DML.

In the mean time this article give some information and tricks to control the JOIN order. Please check if this help you:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25668.transact-sql-join-order.aspx

Basically you should check the execution plan and IO (using SET STATISTICS IO ON), in order to find the best order which fit your database. The article can help you to control the order. Please remember that the same query on two different SQL Server version, or even two different database on the same instance, might behave differently

1. In most cases it best to JOIN the smaller SETs first.
2. remember to test filtering the data before the JOIN operator (using simple JOIN the SQL Server query engine can build a good execution plan and organize the order of operation pretty well. but in complex query with lot of JOINs it fails and we need to control the order in some cases)

**I hope this useful :-)**